# consuming web service from iphone error

Tags: ios, web-services

I've been following the tutorial http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.ca/2011/04/working-with-webservices.html and decided to create my own web service using xaramin and try to call it. But it seems that it just doesn't get called for some reason.

```
Service1.asmx
[WebMethod]
public string printsomeThing(string userData){
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    Console.Out.WriteLine();
    return userData;
}

POST /Service1.asmx
SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/printsomeThing
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: string
Host: string

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <printsomeThing xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <userData>string</userData>
    </printsomeThing>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: string

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <printsomeThingResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <printsomeThingResult>string</printsomeThingResult>
    </printsomeThingResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

ViewController.h

```
 (IBAction)Invoke:(id)sender {
NSString *soapFormat =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\n"
                               "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                               "<soap:Body>\n"
                               "<printsomeThing xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                               "<userData>12</userData>"
                               "</printsomeThing>\n"
                               "</soap:Body>\n"
                               "</soap:Envelope>\n"];
        NSLog(@"The request format is %@",soapFormat);

        //location of the web method
        NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tempuri.org/printsomeThing/Service1.asmx"];

        NSLog(@"web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

        //create connection request
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapFormat length]];

        [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/printsomeThing" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

        [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        //the below encoding is used to send data over the net
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapFormat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        //check if connection is established or not
        NSURLConnection *connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    //[connection release];
    //[webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

    //[theXML release]
}



//recieving xml from the server

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"didstart");
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"printsomeThingResult"]){
        //    if(!soapResults)
        NSLog(@"Innnnn");
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"foundcharacter");
    [nodeContent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"didEndElement %@",nodeContent);
    //if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CelsiusToFahrenheitResult"]) {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"printsomeThingResult"]) {
        finaldata = nodeContent;
        //output.text = finaldata;
        NSLog(@"Final Data is  ===================== %@",finaldata);
    }
    //output.text = finaldata;
}
```

It says that my message got sent but my web service is not receiving it though

```
    2014-06-23 09:22:31.814 SoapServiceTest[3638:60b] The request format is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<printsomeThing xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<userData>12</userData></printsomeThing>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
2014-06-23 09:22:31.817 SoapServiceTest[3638:60b] web url = http://tempuri.org/printsomeThing/Service1.asmx
2014-06-23 09:22:32.436 SoapServiceTest[3638:60b] DONE. Received Bytes: 44115
2014-06-23 09:22:32.438 SoapServiceTest[3638:60b] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" /><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
si_ST=new Date
//]]></script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
sb_gh=function(){return location.hash},sb_sh=function(n){location.hash=n};function _ge(n){return _d.getElementById(n)}_w=window,_d=document,sb_de=_d.documentElement,sb_ie=!!_w.ActiveXObject,sb_i6=sb_ie&&!_w.XMLHttpRequest,sb_st=_w.setTimeout,sb_ct=_w.clearTimeout,sb_gt=function(){return+new Date};sj_evt=new function(){function i(n){return t[n]||(t[n]=[])}var t={},n=this;n.fire=function(n){for(var r=i(n),u=r.e=arguments,t=0;t<r.length;t++)r[t].d?sb_st(sj_wf(r[t],u),r[t].d):r[t](u)},n.bind=function(n,t,r,u){var f=i(n);t.d=u,f.push(t),r&&f.e&&t(f.e)},n.unbind=function(n,i){for(var u=0,r=t[n];r&&u<r.length;u++)if(r[u]==i){r.splice(u,1);break}}};_G={ST:(si_ST?si_ST:new Date),Mkt:"en-CA",RTL:false,Ver:"9_00_0_3007771",IG:"8b539654167049fb97e266c2dce07427",EventID:"acb9ce0d1a43492083fd2e73c90b66f9",V:"homepage",P:"SERP",DA:"NYCr2v2",CID:"2CB5DC5900CE647E2293DA0601DF640F",SUIH:"TA00bzwuo-PiJ79CvDKBVA",PCId:"1",cUrl:"http:\/\/c.bing.com\/c.gif?DI=15074",akamaiSyncUrl:"http:\/\/cms.abmr.net\/pix?cid=1
```

I played around with the encoding as well since the soap message charset is utf 8 and it encoding is 16 but that did seem to work either

Comment: why do you say your server is not getting the request if you have 44KB data sent back to you?

Comment: because i added a Console.WriteLine("test"); on my web service and nothing shows up in the output when i try to access it from the iphone

Comment: I think you have an issue on your server. It definitely replies, but it is not the server page you expect to. Inspect the output you get in `theXML` to understand what info is coming back to you.

Comment: oh yeah it seem that it is printing out the some of the source code from my default.aspx on the web service with a random bunch of css in the end

Comment: Ok, I entered this as a reply, so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving a response from your server, as made plain by the log:

```
Received Bytes: 44115
```

So, definitely the issue is on the server.
It replies, but the request is not routed to the correct page, so it is the wrong page the one that replies.

Inspect the content of `theXML` to understand which page is replying, maybe some sort of 404-page or alike.